Loading an Excel file with changing number of columns using SSIS
I need to load an Excel file using SSIS, with a similar format to this:



EmpID
08.2024
09.2024




12
100
350



and unpivot it to look like this:



EmpID
Date
Value




12
08.2024
100


12
09.2024
350



The total number of columns will continue to change. The number might increase to also hold the time period 11.2024-12.2026, but then the range might change to 09.2025-12.2026. I have no control over these changes and I would like to find an automated solution, instead of manually changing the solution with a new file format.
Is it possible to load this kind of Excel file while unpivoting it in SSIS?
I am not very familiar with SSIS capabilities, nor C# if this is achievable through a Script Component.
I know how to do the unpivoting itself, my question is related to how I can do this with a continuously changing header. I've read about importing the file without the header and map them later on in the database, but the header names are not predictable, so I can't go this route.

I am not the expert here, but I expect that this will require the use of some scripting language (or possibly a HLL) that can (1) First open the excel file and extract just the header row values (column names). (2) Separate those names into a fixed and variable list. (3) Use the variable column list to generate dynamic SQL to (a) create a temporary table with the required columns, (b) read the excel file into that temporary table, and (c) perform a pivot operation to produce your final result. - I'm sure the "dynamic excel to temp table" part has been done before and someone find and post it.

In the desired unpivoted results above, should "cell 3" be "12"? I would also suggest adding at least one more source data row (say EmpID = 13) and then add the corresponding result row mappings.

SSIS require well-defined data. If your data is forever changing then it's not well defined. I  truth, the problem appears to lore be the source data and fixing whatever process keeps altering it. Talking to the vendor and get them to standardise the output.

I don't understand the problem. "I know how to do the unpivoting itself, my question is related to how I can do this with a continuously changing header. I've read about importing the file without the header and map them later on in the database, but the header names are not predictable, so I can't go this route" - Power Pivot can take care of it in Excel so you can just prepare the file at that stage.

I would consider that the input data is well defined - an EmpID column plus one or more MM.YYYY columns. This is perfectly valid in Excel, but does not fit well with the SQL Server data model. That's the point of the question - how best to automate the import while pivoting the data into a for that does fit well with the SQL Server data model. I am not sure if this can be done via a script within SSIS, but I do know that C#, Powershell, and other generalized languages can access the Excel data model to get the column labels, after which is should just be a dynamic SQL solution.

I do not know what can be done in SSIS, but I believe this is achievable in T-SQL.
Based on answers to this question, it appears that you can just use SELECT * INTO #ExcelStaging FROM OPENROWSET(...) to import the Excel data into a temp table without knowing the columns ahead of time. You can then query the resulting table schema to extract the column names of interest, so that you can build and execute dynamic SQL to UNPIVOT the imported data into the desired final form.
The initial import should be able to use a command like:
SELECT *
INTO #ExcelStaging
FROM OPENROWSET(
    'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
    'Excel 12.0;Database=C:\Path\Name.xlsx;HDR=YES',
    'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]'
)

However, if you need to use a file path contained in a variable or parameter, I believe you need to use dynamic SQL (since OPENROWSET does not appear to accept expressions).  Something like:
DECLARE @FilePath NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'C:\Path\FileName.xlsx'
DECLARE @ImportSql = N'
    SELECT *
    INTO #ExcelStaging
    FROM OPENROWSET(
        ''Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'',
        N''Excel 12.0;Database=' + REPLACE(@FilePath, '''', '''''') + N';HDR=YES'',
        ''SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]''
    )
'
PRINT @ImportSql
EXEC (@ImportSql)

The REPLACE(..., '''', '''''') in the above handles file path values that might contain apostrophes. It would be advisable to pre-validate the file path, so as to prevent undesired results is an invalid file path is supplied.
From there, you can query the query the imported columns and perform the unpivot operation as follows:
-- Get list of column names like "MM.YYYY" and convert to
-- a list of the form "[MM.YYYY], [MM.YYYY], [MM.YYYY]"
DECLARE @DynamicColumnList NVARCHAR(MAX) = (
    SELECT STRING_AGG(CAST(QUOTENAME(name) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), ', ')
    FROM tempdb.sys.columns
    WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ExcelStaging')
    AND name LIKE '[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' -- Names like "MM.YYYY"
)

-- Dynamic SQL to select, unpivot, and insert the imported data into the target table
DECLARE @UnpivotSql NVARCHAR(MAX) = '
    INSERT INTO ImportResults (EmpId, Date, Value)
    SELECT U.EmpId, U.Date, U.Value
    FROM (
        SELECT EmpID, ' + @DynamicColumnList + '
        FROM #ExcelStaging
    ) E
    UNPIVOT (
        Value
        FOR Date IN (' + @DynamicColumnList + ')
    ) U
'

-- Execute
PRINT @UnpivotSql 
EXEC (@UnpivotSql )

  -- Show results
SELECT *
FROM ImportResults
ORDER BY EmpId, Date

For import data of the form:



EmpID
Junk
08.2024
09.2024
10.2024




12
X
100
350
400


13
Y
30
40
50



The above will yield the following results:



EmpID
Date
Value




12
08.2024
100


12
09.2024
350


12
10.2024
400


13
08.2024
30


13
09.2024
40


13
10.2024
50



See this db<>fiddle for a partial demonstration of this process. The fiddle environment does not allow for an actual Excel file import.
I'll leave it to you and perhaps some other helpful contributor to handle the details of adapting this to an SSIS package. (As I mentioned before, I have no expertise there.)
I welcome any corrections or other improvements to this post. Feel free to edit directly.

Been several versions since I've done SSIS work, but wrapping the above in a stored procedure and calling it from SSIS seems the way to go to me.
